# Notepad++: Extracting text using replace, words starting with capital letter/mixed case

Tags: notepad++

What I want to do is:

1. Extract any two or more consecutive words that begin with a capital letter.
2. Extract single words with mixed case. (Edit: Mixed case with more than one capital letter, basically Pascal Case of consecutive words that begin with a capital)
3. Add each one as a new line

Example:

```
This is a Text That contains CapitalLetters.
```

Output:

```
Text That
CapitalLetters
```

Comment: Why doesn't `This` selected? It begins with capital letter and it's mixed case.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Pointer - you need to use Regex. Don't know regex? Go learn some, then come back and edit your question with what you've tried if you can't get it to work. SU isn't a regex writing service.

Comment: I'm a normal user, not a power user. I do have the most basic background in regex for the most simple basic tasks I usually use it for like replacing simple word patterns or numbers, but with this, I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in 2 step:

- First step: keep only the wanted words

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:[A-Z]\w*(?:\h+[A-Z]\w*)+|[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\w.]+\h*`
- Replace with: `\n` OR `\r\n` depending on platform
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
(?:             # start non capture group
    [A-Z]           # a capital letter at beginning of word
    \w*             # 0 or more word character
    (?:             # start non capture group
        \h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
        [A-Z]           # a capital letter at beginning of word
        \w*             # 0 or more word character
    )+              # end group, must appear 1 or more times
  |               # OR
    [A-Z]           # a capital letter at beginning of word
    \w*             # 0 or more word character
    [A-Z]           # a capital letter somewhere in the word
    \w*             # 0 or more word character
)               # end group
\b              # word boundary
(*SKIP)         # Skip what was matched
(*FAIL)         #   Assert the match failed
  |               # OR
[\w.]+          # 1 or more word character or dot
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

- second step: remove empty lines

```
Menu Edit >> Line Operations >> Remove Empty Lines
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! It does leave a few punctuations in, but for my purposes, I only need to extract, it doesn't need to be clean.

Comment: @chipmunkbarrier: You're welcome, glad it helps. You can add the punctuation in the character class: `[\w.,;?!]+`